# Do stuff inside a `for` in a Thread

Tags: java, android

```
@Override

    public void run() {

        act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override

            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < randomNumber.size(); i++) {

                    Log.d("N",randomNumber.get(i).toString());

                    if (randomNumber.get(i).intValue() == 1) imgColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    if (randomNumber.get(i).intValue() == 2) imgColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    if (randomNumber.get(i).intValue() == 3) imgColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    if (randomNumber.get(i).intValue() == 4) imgColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1750);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }

                    imgColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(400);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }

                }

                Toast.makeText(act, "Ripeti la sequenza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I have a number list, with numbers from 1 to 4. I want to picture the ImageView according to the numbers in the list, but I need a sequence of colors, so I need (for example) show the RED color, after wait 1,75 seconds, and after the GREEN and so on, but it doesn't work ! What should I do ?

Comment: didnt get exactly what you wanna do

Comment: I have a number list, with numbers from 1 to 4. I want to picture the ImageView according to the numbers in the list, but I need a sequence of colors, so I need (for example) show the RED color, after wait 1,75 seconds, and after the GREEN and so on...

Comment: You need to clarify your question a bit. Provide proper context like where is this code going to run (activity, fragment, inside an asynctask, etc). What are you trying to achieve with what type of elements, etc?

Comment: *"but it doesn't work!"* Pretty overused but useless for anyone trying to help you. Is it giving an error? Is it doing something else than what you expected? If so, what is doing and what did you expect instead? This is what you should explain in your question. We don't read your mind.

Comment: please never sleep the UI thread, this will block the entire user interface

Comment: This part of code is inside a thread, that I call when a button is pressed in the main activity. When the thread run the app stops for some seconds (the time to execute the for cicle) and after color my imageview black. But I need that the imageview change color for 7 times (the arraylist length) and every time that it change color it has to wait 1,75 seconds, but this doesn't happen. Hope I was clear as much as possible

Comment: @Chris623 So, what should I do? I've also tried with wait() function, but it gives me the same problem...

Comment: the example in the answer by Baydalka is good, try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such tasks Thread isn't the best choice. I recommend you to use View.postDelayed method. So you should get something like that.

```
void setRandomColor(){
   if(!hasRandomColor())
      return;

   imgColor.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());

   imgColor.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
     void run(){
        setRandomColor();
     }
   }, 1750); // update color again after 1.75 sec
}

... 

setRandomColor();
```

Comment: Little question... How can I exit from this cicle ? I've tried with return; but it doesn't work

Comment: Just don't call postDelayed if you need to stop.